# Cannot find the specific element with Find class in WatIN

Tags: watin

I am trying to automate rest client but when I try to enter a value in the URL text-box it does not find the object by id and even by name

What I actually did was `Find.ById` and `Find.ByName` but it does not seem to find the element.

Comment: Please post the HTML content and the code what you have tried.

Comment: <input id="request-url" type="url" placeholder="http://www.example.com" style="margin: 0 auto; width: -moz-calc(100% - 380px);" autocomplete="on" name="request-url" rel="tooltip" title="hotkey: u">                                            Part of the code I used to search for the object is as shown below                                    browser.TextField(WatiN.Core.Find.ByName("request-url")).TypeText("abcd");                                               browser.TextField(WatiN.Core.Find.ById("request-url")).TypeText("abcd");

Comment: Are you trying to enter a value in the URL? What is the output/error you get?

Comment: yes am trying to put a URL but i get this error {"Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' equals 'request-url' at chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html"}

Comment: Since the Input type is of type 'URL', WatiN will not recognize the element as text-field.  This is by design.

Comment: so you mean to say that there is no way I can automate this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do it, you need to override the existing functionality. Below is the code to get the textfield of type 'URL'.

```
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "url", Index = 5)]
public class CustomTextField : Element<CustomTextField>
{
    public CustomTextField(DomContainer domContainer, INativeElement element) : base(domContainer, element) { }
    public CustomTextField(DomContainer domContainer, ElementFinder finder) : base(domContainer, finder) { }
}
```